# Determine number of elements in array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I realise, that the title suggests an easy answer. Please read this through, though. In my undergraduate studies I'm having a course called computational mathematics and numerical analysis where I learn C++. Now I started coding in VBA yesterday - just for fun. I've tried to make a program, that can calculate the roots of a polynomial. After some back and forth I've managed to write all the code down. The last thing i want to do is print all the roots in Excel. For that I'm using an array called 'arroot'. The Sub below is my Main:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fx As Double, Dim dffx As Double, Dim n As Integer
    Dim x As Double, Dim root As Double, Dim arroot()
    Dim a(15) As Long, Dim i As Integer

    Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
    Call PolyCoef(n, a)
    i = 0
    Do
         Call Table(n, a, x, fx, dffx)
         Call NewRapHorner(n, a, fx, dffx, root)
         Call HornerDivPol(n, a, root)
         arroot(i) = root
         i = i + 1
    Loop While (Not n = 0)
    Call Printroot(arroot)           
End Sub
```

You can see, that I'm saving the values in the array, always updating 'i' to ensure, that I get every value. The code responsible for printing the root is below:

```
Private Sub Printroot(arroot())

    Sheet1.Range("G3").Value = "Root"
    Sheet1.Range("H3").Value = "x-value"
    For i = 0 To UBound(arroot()) Step 1
        Sheet1.Range("G" & 4 + i).Value = i + 1 & ". root"
        Sheet1.Range("H" & 4 + i).Value = arroot(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

**My Problem:** When doing this, I run into problems - the code won't run. When I define the array as Dim arroot (15) the code works. The only issue is, that I print too many 'i + 1 & ". root"'s. How can I solve this issue? I want my array to be as big as the number of roots. If it makes sense putting it this way: I want the brackets for the array somehow to be empty, so it automatically adjusts.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

As requested, here's the complete code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fx As Double, Dim dffx As Double, Dim n As Integer
    Dim x As Double, Dim root As Double, Dim arroot(15)
    Dim a(15) As Long, Dim i As Integer

    Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
    Call PolyCoef(n, a)
    i = 0
    Do
        Call Table(n, a, x, fx, dffx)
        Call NewRapHorner(n, a, fx, dffx, root)
        Call HornerDivPol(n, a, root)
        arroot(i) = root
        i = i + 1
    Loop While (Not n = 0)
    Call Printroot(arroot)    
End Sub

'Main Ends. Subs used in main are defined:

Private Sub PolyCoef(n As Integer, a() As Long)
    Dim e As Integer

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Enter n for polynomial"
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = InputBox("Enter n", "Degree of the polynomial")
    n = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
    e = n
    Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = "Coefficients:"
    Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = "Values:"

    For i = 0 To n Step 1
        Sheet1.Range("A" & i + 4).Value = i + 1 & ". coefficient, a" & e
        Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 4).Value = InputBox("Enter coefficient", i + 1 & ". coefficient")
        a(i) = Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 4).Value
        e = e - 1
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub Horner(n As Integer, a() As Long, x As Double, fx As Double, dffx As Double)
    Dim e As Integer, Dim b(15), Dim c(15)

    b(0) = a(0)
    For i = 1 To n Step 1
        b(i) = a(i) + x * b(i - 1)
    Next
    c(0) = b(0)
    For i = 1 To n Step 1
        c(i) = b(i) + x * c(i - 1)
    Next
    fx = b(n)
    dffx = c(n - 1)
End Sub

Private Sub Table(n As Integer, a() As Long, x As Double, fx As Double, dffx As Double)
    Dim xmax As Double, Dim dx As Double

    x = InputBox("Enter first x-value", "Enter xmin")
    xmax = InputBox("Enter last x-value", "Enter xmax")
    dx = (xmax - x) / 19
    Sheet1.Range("D3").Value = "x-value"
    Sheet1.Range("E3").Value = "f(x)"
    For i = 0 To 19 Step 1
        Call Horner(n, a, x, fx, dffx)
        Sheet1.Range("D" & 4 + i).Value = x
        Sheet1.Range("E" & 4 + i).Value = fx
        x = x + dx
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub NewRapHorner(n As Integer, a() As Long, fx As Double, dffx As Double, root As Double)
    Dim xnew As Double, Dim xold As Double, Dim eps As Double
    Dim ite As Integer, Dim x0 As Double, Dim i As Integer

    x0 = InputBox("Enter x-value close to root", "x-value")
    eps = InputBox("Enter tolerance", "Tolerance")
    ite = InputBox("Enter number of max iterations", "Max iterations")
    i = 0
    xnew = x0
    root = 0
    Do
        xold = xnew
        Call Horner(n, a, xnew, fx, dffx)
        xnew = xnew - (fx / dffx)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While (Abs(xnew - xold) > eps And i < ite)
    If i >= ite Then
        MsgBox "Number of max iterations has been exeeded"
    Else
        root = xnew
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HornerDivPol(n As Integer, a() As Long, root As Double)
    Dim b(15) As Long

    b(0) = a(0)
    For i = 1 To n Step 1
        b(i) = a(i) + root * b(i - 1)
    Next   
    For i = 1 To n Step 1
        a(i) = b(i)
    Next 
    n = n - 1
End Sub

Private Sub Printroot(arroot())

    Sheet1.Range("G3").Value = "Root"
    Sheet1.Range("H3").Value = "x-value"
    For i = 0 To UBound(arroot()) Step 1
        Sheet1.Range("G" & 4 + i).Value = i + 1 & ". root"
        Sheet1.Range("H" & 4 + i).Value = arroot(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried ReDim?

Comment: The code for your Printroot seems fine and should be printing all the elements in your array as they are. The only thing you might want to consider changing is `For i = LBound(arroot) To UBound(arroot)` due to the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx So, if the array does not contain what you expect then there is a problem with the code generating the array (which is not shown in the question).

Comment: @Ralph As the article states "Because the default base is 0, the Option Base statement is never required." and because i is being set to 0 before arroot(i) = root is called, the lower bound will be zero.

Comment: Can you please post your complete code, so I can step through it and see where the error is?

Comment: Please narrow down your post to the essential part, clearly specify the issue and include the minimal amount of code directly related to the issue. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @ScottMarcus We don't know how the array is populated. So, we cannot know if it has been populated starting with a 1 or a 0. If SAFD is getting too many returns then this might be one of the reasons.

Comment: in VB6/VBA an array definition of arr(15) is an array of length 16, going from 0 to to 15, rather than like most languages which will create an array with a length of 15 going from 0 to 14.

Comment: To add on...if you declare an array with empty brackets, you would need to use the ReDim Preserve statement each iteration through the loop in order to allocate the array you are using. The array with empty brackets can hold nothing. Try to change your declaration to Dim arroot (14) which will give you 15 elements numbered 0 to 14.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I've added the code, Scott. @Jeremy, the problem isn't the size of the arrays, I could have used 14, 15 or even 100 (if I understand your statement correctly)

Comment: @SAFD you stated you were printing too many times, so you need to ensure that the size of the array has the number of elemets you expect in it.

Comment: @Ralph We do know how the array is being populated, it's in the Main method. i is initialized at 0 and then in the do/loop the array uses i to populate the array. upon the first iteration i=0.

Comment: @SAFD Thanks for posting all the code. I will go through it in more detail tomorrow, but upon first stepping, I notice that most of your variables are declared in `Sub Main`, making them local to Main, but you are using them throughout your other Subs, which creates new values. If you move those declarations to the very top of the code module (the General Declarations section), does this solve the problem? Even if it doesn't, I still think you need them there. Also, when declaring multiple variables on a single line, only write `Dim` once, as in: `Dim x As Integer, y As String, z As Long`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not very efficient for what you want to do in VBA.
I would suggest to create a collection like:

```
Public yourArray As New Collection
```

Adding element with the same type it will dynamically adjust its size. Below I show how I would add elements to the collection.

```
Public yourArray As New Collection

Sub trieal()

i = 10
Do Until i = 1
    yourArray.Add i
    i = i - 1

Loop

For Each e In yourArray
    Debug.Print (e)
Next
End Sub
```

That solves your problem of looping through the elements of your "array".

Comment: Collections start counting from 1, arrays start from zero. Collections are for storing Objects, arrays are for storing primitive data types. Collections are not as efficient as arrays. Naming a Collection yourArray is confusing because collections and arrays are two fundamentally different containers.

Comment: I agree what you said. I had similar problem using arrays like it was indicated in the question and I thought since that worked for me it could work for someone else, too.

Comment: Then you simply weren't looping through the array properly and weren't keeping track of your counter accurately.  Arrays are for primitive data - - always.